# In PrimeFaces (4.0) confirm dialog, how do I ensure 'No' is in focus by default?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

As you can see from the image below, 'yes' button gets the primary focus. Can you ensure that 'No' is in focus without swapping the buttons around, perhaps with an attribute?

[image]

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. Couldn't find the attribute 'focus' for p:confirmDialogue in the doco as well.

Comment: Okay , seem like known issue / feature. Optimus prime said use this http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2559 somebody tried this http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=41290 but did not helpthem.

Comment: This feature is available for a `<p:dialog>` through `<p:dialog focus="buttonId" ...>` as mentioned [here](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2559) but the same is however, untrue for a `<p:confirmDialog>`. You might need some custom JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: you can use <p:confirmdialog > with a little bit extra codes

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only way is to swap the buttons in the xhtml. But you can keep the order of appearance in the dialog with `float:left` on the Yes button.

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" style="float:left;" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```